# Run javascript command from within R package

Tags: javascript, r, npx

I would like to generate identicons with [Jdenticon](https://jdenticon.com/js-api/cli-usage.html) from within an R package. So, given a set of arguments in R variables including an output file name, I'd like a function that will return a filename refering to the generated Jdenticon (either PNG or SVG) that I can use (eg to read into Rmarkdown documents).

So I'd like a function that does something like:

```
create_jdenticon('dj23idfsb', size = 100, format = 'svg')
# [1] "/var/folders/59/r7wjy0gn6yv59w19694x5gy80000gp/T//RtmpjDwDfq/jdenticon_dj23idfsb_100.svg"
```

I can write most of the R function, I'm just not sure how to setup and run the npx command required from within R (or even if this is the right approach).

I see that the [packer](https://github.com/JohnCoene/packer) package has an [npx](https://search.r-project.org/CRAN/refmans/packer/html/npx.html) command, but I'm not sure whether this package really does what I want or how to start.

Any pointers would be appreciated.

[The reason I need it to be Jdenticons in particular is that I'm using Jdenticons elsewhere on the web, and they need to match (so solutions using R packages that do the same thing but generate *different* identicons will not work).]

Comment: do you have `npx`?

Comment: Do you mean "me" or "hypothetical user of the R package"? I have it, but I don't know whether someone who might install the package would.

Comment: A full answer to your question would need to be a pretty detailed tutorial on integrating Node.js into your R package, but this resource should get you going: https://colinfay.me/node-r-package/. I tested this out with Jdenticon and this will work for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a minimally working version of Jdenticon for R:

https://github.com/mattroumaya/jdenticon

The main steps in creating this type of wrapper for a Node.js package are:

1. Installing node dependencies in your package's `inst` folder.
2. Writing any JavaScript scripts that you intend to run from your R package.
3. Writing an R function that calls your JavaScript function(s) using the `processx` package.
4. Finally, bundling everything to avoid the R user from having to run `npm install` to initialize `node_modules`.